# array_walk params userdata modified

Tags: php, segmentation-fault

I found something strange in my application.

Gonna be hard to describe my prob because I can't share you a reproductible sample.

The main problem is about the third params of array_walk function.

```
$row = array("user_id" => 1, "first_name" => "bobby");
$data = array("user_id" => "fc_name", "first_name" => "fc2_name", "email" => "fc3_name");
$res = array_walk( $row, 'fu', $aParams);

function fu(&$cell, $key, $data) {
    return call_user_func_array($data[$cell], array($cell, $key, $data));
}
```

When I ran the script, it was aborted without error.
After debugging I found that $data is modified and become a recursive array.

```
Array
 *RECURSION*
```

That I can't understand is how $data can be modified while is passed by copy ?
I know you don't have all information about execution and there is many other call in call_user_func_array.

Thanks

PS: I log all trace with Xdebug but I can't find something strange.

---

**UPDATE1**: If i translate array_walk in foreach loop no problem

**UPDATE2**: Update1 allowed me to understand the problem is not pure PHP code that why I was looking for "stack over flow" (real one :)) or segment fault. And i found this bug on official php bug report https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61730 and my php version is not fixed (5.3.2) i checked my array.c. The scenario is close to mine so I will update php when I can (enterprise process ...).

I expect a lot of this fix.

Comment: Should `$aParams` be `$data` in the `array_walk()` call?

Comment: yeah it's a copy of $aParams passed in params

Comment: I found something interesting on official php bug report (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61730). I check my array.c the fix is not applied (5.3.2) I will try with new php version soon (I can't change version easily atm but I will report when it will be done)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61730 fixed on php 5.3.10
Just updated php